# Deleting dataset branches in Palantir Foundry

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-code-workbooks, palantir-foundry-api

is there a simple way to delete a specific dataset branch? deleting the related code authoring branch doesn't remove the ones already built in the dataset.

As I understand it, it should be possible to remove them via the API (see https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/api/datasets-resources/branches/delete-branch/) -- but isn't there a way to do it from *within* the platform?

I explored various options within the interface without success (both in the Dataset Preview, Data Lineage, and Code Repository menus). I did also try to write some local python code to submit the requests to the API with a token I generated, but was unsuccessful (unclear to me if that depends on some organizational proxy setting/ limitation or if it was just my code that wasn't correct).

Comment: Strictly speaking it doesn't answer your question, hence posting as comment: Once you've deleted the branch in authoring, the platform will take care of deleting orphans datasets branches. It can take a bit of time, but this will happen automatically.

Comment: I think, but not sure, that you would need to delete all transactions of the branch if you want it to disappear faster https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75411123/how-do-i-remove-the-latest-transaction-in-a-foundry-incremental-build-transform

Answer (score 0):

If you've been able to delete the branch in authoring, then Foundry Retention will eventually kick in and clean up any underlying transactions and branches. The period between deleting the branch in authoring and retention kicking in will vary based on how retention has been configured on your Foundry instance. If you want to speed up this process, you can also achieve it by hitting API endpoints directly, though you might need to verify that you have the correct permissions to delete a branch.